# Laptop & External monitor issues

Tags: nvidia, multi-monitor, kubuntu

**Expected behavior:**
plug in an HDMI cable to my laptop and use external monitor.

**What I need help with:**
How can I ensure I don't bork a fresh install trying to get my nvidia graphics card to play nice with my OS?

**Overview:**
I have a T15p Gen 1 Thinkpad with integrated Intel graphics and a nvidia graphic card running kubunutu 22.04 LTS (no dual boot).
I finally got my lab to get me an HDMI & HDM to display port adapter so I could use an external screen but I my system does not recognize that the HDMI is connected.
My laptop has a nvidia graphic card, but I've never been able to get it running correctly without somehow breaking my system and having to completely re-install kubuntu.
I've been able to rescue my system about as many times as I have broken it since I started using kubuntu this year. I'm getting a little tired of it to be honest, I just want to use the hardware, its why I forked over a little extra money for a thinkpad expecting it to play nice with ubuntu.

**Details & attempts so far:**
The second monitor has an output of 1920x1080 60hz, my laptop monitor is 3840x2160 60hz; so the refresh rate shouldn't be an issue.

I am using X.Org. X server -- Nouveau display; because of the issues I outlined previously.

I had run the NVIDIA driver metapackage nvidia-driver-525 on the last install of this OS, which had the exact same issues I described, no dual monitor support which lead to my Nth rebuild of the OS due to some poor choices.

I have secure boot turned off.

Sys info

```
$ inxi -b
System:
  Host:... Kernel: 5.15.0-58-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.24.7 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20TN001HUS v: ThinkPad T15p Gen 1
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: LENOVO model: 20TN001HUS v: SDK0J40697 WIN
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: LENOVO v: N30ET48W (1.31 )
    date: 10/07/2022
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 40.8 Wh (62.8%) condition: 65.0/68.0 Wh (95.6%)
    volts: 11.5 min: 11.5
CPU:
  Info: 6-core Intel Core i7-10850H [MT MCP] speed (MHz): avg: 1129
    min/max: 800/5100
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 3 GB Max-Q] driver: nouveau
    v: kernel
  Device-3: Luxvisions Innotech Integrated Camera type: USB
    driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 resolution: 3840x2160~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.5
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi driver: iwlwifi
  Device-2: Intel Ethernet I219-LM driver: e1000e
```

Display info

```
$sudo lshw -C display
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 3 GB Max-Q]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:162 memory:ad000000-adffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:90000000-91ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=3840x2160 resolution=3840,2160 visual=truecolor xres=3840 yres=2160
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:163 memory:6040000000-6040ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Driver info to make sure there aren't any rouge nvidia drivers running.

```
$ lsmod | grep nouveau
nouveau              2306048  1
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
drm_ttm_helper         16384  1 nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,nouveau
ttm                    86016  3 drm_ttm_helper,i915,nouveau
drm_kms_helper        311296  2 i915,nouveau
drm                   622592  20 drm_kms_helper,drm_ttm_helper,i915,ttm,nouveau
wmi                    32768  5 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,wmi_bmof,think_lmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  61440  3 thinkpad_acpi,i915,nouveau

$ lsmod | grep video
uvcvideo              106496  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       77824  4 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops
videodev              258048  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     65536  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
video                  61440  3 thinkpad_acpi,i915,nouveau
```

The display manager doesn't recognize that there is anything connected. When I use the built in F7 extended display on my keyboard, I can choose to extend my screen. When I do, the display configuration refreshes but returns to the same screen, with no option for a second monitor.

While I was trying to brute force my way into a second monitor, xrandr lists 2 HDMI ports, but I only have 1 port.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  60.00
   3200x1800     60.00
   2880x1620     60.00
   2560x1600     60.00
   2560x1440     60.00
   2048x1536     60.00
   1920x1440     60.00
   1856x1392     60.00
   1792x1344     60.00
   2048x1152     60.00
   1920x1200     60.00
   1920x1080     60.00
   1600x1200     60.00
   1680x1050     60.00
   1400x1050     60.00
   1600x900      60.00
   1280x1024     60.00
   1400x900      60.00
   1280x960      60.00
   1440x810      60.00
   1368x768      60.00
   1280x800      60.00
   1280x720      60.00
   1024x768      60.00
   960x720       60.00
   928x696       60.00
   896x672       60.00
   1024x576      60.00
   960x600       60.00
   960x540       60.00
   800x600       60.00
   840x525       60.00
   864x486       60.00
   700x525       60.00
   800x450       60.00
   640x512       60.00
   700x450       60.00
   640x480       60.00
   720x405       60.00
   684x384       60.00
   640x360       60.00
   512x384       60.00
   512x288       60.00
   480x270       60.00
   400x300       60.00
   432x243       60.00
   320x240       60.00
   360x202       60.00
   320x180       60.00
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

It looks like HDMI2 is maybe the port to use, but I'm a little confused as too why there are two HDMI ports.

Any ways, here are the xrandr commands I tried:

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 1920x1080
xrandr --addmode HDMI-2 1920x1080
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080
xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*eDP-1 3840/344x2160/194+0+0  eDP-1
# weird....
$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 2
 0: +*eDP-1 3840/344x2160/194+0+0  eDP-1
 1: +HDMI-2 1920/508x1080/286+0+0  HDMI-2 # Whew.. OK thats a good sign
```

Running xrandr does not show any thing is connected and looking at display configuration and F7 don't give me any changed behavior.

```
...
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00
...
```

After running that code, heres some dmesg output:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep nouveau
[    1.605229] nouveau: detected PR support, will not use DSM
[    1.605262] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[    1.605633] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: NVIDIA GP107 (137000a1)
[    1.679239] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bios: version 86.07.90.00.b9
[    1.681314] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: pmu: firmware unavailable
[    1.746332] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: 3072 MiB GDDR5
[    2.065653] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: VRAM: 3072 MiB
[    2.065654] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: GART: 536870912 MiB
[    2.065655] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: BIT table 'A' not found
[    2.065656] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: BIT table 'L' not found
[    2.065657] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: Pointer to TMDS table not found
[    2.065658] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB version 4.1
[    2.065931] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: MM: using COPY for buffer copies
[    2.066096] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.3.1 20120801 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[    2.066098] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: Disabling PCI power management to avoid bug

$ sudo dmesg | grep nvidia
[    4.478592] audit: type=1400 audit(1673601942.061:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=625 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.478598] audit: type=1400 audit(1673601942.061:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=625 comm="apparmor_parser"



$ sudo dmesg | grep HDMI
[    0.305663] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    4.685570] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input13
[    4.685617] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
[    4.685683] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input15
[    4.685726] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input16
[    4.685779] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17

$ sudo dmesg | grep vga
[    0.765647] pci 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: VGA device added: decodes=io+mem,owns=mem,locks=none
[    0.765647] pci 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: bridge control possible
[    0.765647] pci 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: setting as boot device
[    0.765647] vgaarb: loaded
[    1.623621] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    1.673431] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=mem
[    3.454663] vga_switcheroo: enabled

$ sudo dmesg | grep graphics
[    0.091329] Reserving Intel graphics memory at [mem 0x7a800000-0x7e7fffff]
[    0.917098] efifb: showing boot graphics

$ sudo dmesg | grep intel
[    0.915864] intel_pstate: Intel P-state driver initializing
[    0.916670] intel_pstate: HWP enabled
[    0.956370] intel_pmc_core INT33A1:00:  initialized
[    1.505507] intel-lpss 0000:00:15.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.369069] intel_pch_thermal 0000:00:12.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.395582] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    4.395585] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain dram
[    4.486163] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    4.486166] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
[    4.486168] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    4.486169] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain dram
[    4.486170] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain psys
[    4.501921] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040380
[    4.508606] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-19-0-4.sfi
[    4.516577] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0004 -> 0006)
[    4.525944] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    4.678179] intel_tcc_cooling: Programmable TCC Offset detected
[    6.404500] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-19-0-4.ddc
```

These outputs seems like something but all I've found are some vauge mentions of opensource/proprietary firmware information I don't quiet understand. Given my history, I'd rather not proceed without any advice.

```
...
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bios: version 86.07.90.00.b9
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: pmu: firmware unavailable
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: 3072 MiB GDDR5
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: VRAM: 3072 MiB
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: GART: 536870912 MiB
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: BIT table 'A' not found
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: BIT table 'L' not found
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: Pointer to TMDS table not found
...
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: Disabling PCI power management to avoid bug
```

I still need to find a second HDMI cable to test, but could the Adapter Display port to HDMI have any part of this?

I'm not sure what else ya'll need to help me with this, please let me know. I appreciate your time and any help you could provide!

Comment: I've had two thinkpads, a  T460p and my current P14s, both had hybrid graphics. In both cases, I configured them to use the NVIDIA card and both would happily connect to and drive external monitors. Maybe the open source nouveau can't do it? It might be worth posting a question about your NVIDIA issues instead. Could this be something as simple as a bad DP->HDMI adapter as you suggest? Does something like `xrandr --output HDMI-2 --auto` do anything?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried appending auto, and the HDMI is still listed as disconnected in xrandr. 

I'll try using the proprietary drivers again if I don't get any other suggestions. That issue is the typical boot to black screen issue. It seems to be a coin flip if I can get the laptop monitor functioning again after that.

Comment: Weird. I haven't had a laptop with that specific card, but both of my thinkpads had NVIDIA cards and on both I didn't have a lot of trouble configuring it. Mind you, I'm on Arch so I followed the _excellent_ Arch documentation. That's usually applicable to other systems as well so it might be worth taking a look there, especially at the Troubleshooting tips: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA/Troubleshooting Also, have a look at https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ThinkWiki and see if there is anything about your model there.

Comment: thanks for the link @terdon. I switched to the NVIDIA driver and found I didn't have an xorg.conf file. I had nvidia make one and I preformed a reboot. I'm back too a black screen problem. Trying to get into grub is impossible because it freezes. I'll create another question.